# bit shift multiplication in c not using powers of 2

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

How can I perform multiplication by 36 using bit-shifting?  Isn't it only possible to multiply by powers of 2?  For example:

```
unsigned x = 4; // binary 00000000 00000000 00000000 00001000
unsigned y = x << 3; // multiply by 8, resulting in binary 00000000 ... 00100000
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes, bit-shifting is powers of 2

Comment: `y=(x<< 5) + (x <<2)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't multiply by a non-power of 2 by bit shifting alone.

But you can break it down using addition and multiplication:

```
x * 36 = x * (32 + 4)
       = (x * 32) + (x * 4)
```

Since `32` and `4` are powers of `2` (`2^5` and `2^2` respectively), you can perform those as separate shifts and add the results.

Comment: Perfect!  I don't know why I didn't think of this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't by bit-shifting alone. Bit-shifting a binary number can only multiply or divide by powers of 2, exactly as you say. Similarly, you can only multiply or divide a decimal number by powers of 10 by place-shifting (e.g. 3 can become 30, 300, 0.3, or 0.03, but never 0.02 or 99).

---

But you could break the 36 down into sums of powers of two.

That is, you can split 36 into 32 + 4, which is 2^5 + 2^2. By the verbiage you have used ("write code that uses shifts"), the only requirement is to use bit-shifting and it should be allowed to perform additional operations as long as this requirement is met.

That is,

```
x * 36 = x * (32 + 4) = 32x + 4x = (2^5)x + (2^2)x = (x << 5) + (x << 2)
```

With this understanding, the simplest implementation would then be to add the two shifted values:

```
int result = (x << 5) + (x << 2);
```

Comment: @P0W Yes that's what I meant.